# How to pass dictionary as a parameter in the method in Swift?

Tags: methods, parameters, swift, alamofire

I have created following method in my code:

```
func SignIn(objDictionary:Dictionary<String,String>)
{
    //Body of method
}
```

I need to pass the following dictionary as a parameter in this method which is defined below:

```
let objSignInDictionary:Dictionary = ["email":emailTextField.text, "password":passwordTextField.text]
```

How can I pass this dictionary in the above method as a parameter?

This should be noted that method is in another class and I am calling the method by creating its object as follows:

```
let obj = Services()
```

SignIn is defined in Services.swift class
so I am trying to call it like

```
obj.SignIn(objSignInDictionary)
```

but getting following error

```
"String!" is not identical to "String"
```

Where I am wrong and how it can be fixed. I am stuck here since couple of days.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you alt+click `objSignInDictionary` in Xcode you will see its inferred as `[String : String!]`. You can fix this by explicitly setting `objSignInDictionary` type:

```
let objSignInDictionary:[String:String] = ["email":emailTextField.text, "password":passwordTextField.text]
```