# How do i pass a dictionary as a function parameter?

Tags: swift, dictionary

I am trying to pass a dictionary as a function parameter. I have the following function

```
func makeAndAddVisitorRecord2(visitorDict: Dictionary) -> ABRecordRef <AnyObject, AnyObject> {
    let visitorRecord: ABRecordRef = ABPersonCreate().takeRetainedValue()
    ABRecordSetValue(visitorRecord, kABPersonFirstNameProperty, visitorDict[1], nil)
    ABRecordSetValue(visitorRecord, kABPersonLastNameProperty, visitorDict[2], nil)
    //ABRecordSetValue(visitorRecord, kABPersonEmailProperty, visitorDict[5], nil)

    let phoneNumbers: ABMutableMultiValue =
    ABMultiValueCreateMutable(ABPropertyType(kABMultiStringPropertyType)).takeRetainedValue()
    ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(phoneNumbers, visitorDict["visitorPhone"], kABPersonPhoneMainLabel, nil)
    ABRecordSetValue(visitorRecord, kABPersonPhoneProperty, phoneNumbers, nil)

    ABAddressBookAddRecord(addressBookRef, visitorRecord, nil)
    saveAddressBookChanges()

    return visitorRecord
}
```

Which i like to trigger by

```
func addVisitorToContacts(sender: AnyObject) {
    //let visitor = ListVisitors[visitorButton.tag]
    var visitorDict:[Int:String] = [1:"\(visitorName)", 2:"\(visitorCompany)", 3:"\(visitorCity)",
        4:"\(visitorPhone)", 5:"\(visitorEmail)"]

    let visitorRecord: ABRecordRef = makeAndAddVisitorRecord2(visitorDict)
    let contactAddedAlert = UIAlertController(title: "\(visitorName) was successfully added.",
        message: nil, preferredStyle: .Alert)
    contactAddedAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Cancel, handler: nil))
    presentViewController(contactAddedAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

But makeAndAddVisitorRecord2 compiles an error

```
 Cannot specialize non-generic type 'ABRecordRef' (aka 'AnyObject')
```

[EDIT 1] workable solution but not optimal as i am not using my Visitor struct

```
func makeAndAddVisitorRecord2(visitorDict: Dictionary <Int, String>) -> ABRecordRef  {
```

[EDIT 2] as @rsmoz pointed out i should use my Visitor struct

```
class Visitor {

var visitorName : String
var visitorCompany : String
var visitorPlace : String
var visitorPhone : String
var visitorEmail : String

init(visitorName: String, visitorCompany: String, visitorPlace: String, visitorPhone: String, visitorEmail: String) {
    self.visitorName = visitorName
    self.visitorCompany = visitorCompany
    self.visitorPlace = visitorPlace
    self.visitorPhone = visitorPhone
    self.visitorEmail = visitorEmail
}
```

}

So i have a ListVisitors class which generates some Visitors and looks like

```
class ListVisitors{
    static var sharedInstance = [Visitor]()

static func load()
    {
        // @todo: stored and loaded data
        var visitor = Visitor(visitorName: "From Class Matt", visitorCompany: "Google", visitorPlace: "San Diego", visitorPhone: "94888484", visitorEmail: "matt@google.com")
        sharedInstance = [visitor]

        visitor = Visitor(visitorName: "From Class John", visitorCompany: "nike", visitorPlace: "New York", visitorPhone: "94888484", visitorEmail: "john@nike.com")
        //        ListVisitors.sharedInstance += [visitor]
        sharedInstance += [visitor]
...
}
}
```

And in my main controller i have a table view and a selected row sends the visitor details to detailcontroller (HOW can i have the selected visitor struct in detail view controller?? Should i pass let selectedVisitor to the detail view controller?)

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?){
if (segue.identifier == "visitorDetails") {

            if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(sender as! UITableViewCell) {

                let selectedVisitor = lVisitors[indexPath.row] as Visitor

                let detailVC = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewController

                detailVC.visitorName = selectedVisitor.visitorName
                detailVC.visitorCompany = selectedVisitor.visitorCompany
                detailVC.visitorPlace = selectedVisitor.visitorPlace
                detailVC.visitorPhone = selectedVisitor.visitorPhone
                detailVC.visitorEmail = selectedVisitor.visitorEmail

            } // .end accessory select

        } // .end segue
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass dictionary as a parameter in the methind in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26096178/how-to-pass-dictionary-as-a-parameter-in-the-methind-in-swift)

Comment: Why do you need `Int:String` dictionary? Just use array.

Comment: @stek29 hmm i tried it `let visitorArr: Array = [String]() and visitorArr["visitorName"] = visitorName` and tried to pass the array as parameter. Could you provide a simple code example??? Any why would using an array > dictionary??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do with `ABRecordRef <AnyObject, AnyObject>`, but the `<>` syntax is for specifying a generic type. Like, an array that holds strings is `Array<String>`. `ABRecordRef` is not a generic type.

The Dictionary needs to have the types it holds specified in the parameter: `Dictionary<String, Int>`

Also, you're treating a dictionary like an array. Better to use a dictionary as it's meant to be used. Instead of `[1:"\(visitorName)"]`, why not `["visitorName":visitorName]`? That way you can access it like `dict["visitorName"]` You also don't need to do `"\(visitorName)"` if visitorName is a String to begin with. Just use the variable directly.

It would be even better, though, to represent a Visitor as a struct, not an array or dictionary:

```
struct Visitor {
    let name: String
    let company: String
    let city: String
    let phone: String //Yes, this should be a String and not an Int
    let email: String
}
```

And you could set it like this:

```
let v = Visitor(name: "Joe", company: "A Corp", city: "New York", phone: "+44 392 39275 22", email: "joe@smith.org")
```

And access it like this:

```
v.name
```

And that's just so much cleaner and safer. Now your code won't have any errors from accidentally accessing the wrong key on a dictionary.

Oh, and you should be using the [Contacts framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Contacts/Reference/Contacts_Framework/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015328) these days, not ABAddressBook.

Comment: Actually, `Dictionary<Int:String>` won't work. It's `Dictionary<Int, String>`. Use a comma, not a colon.

Comment: @rsmoz, i ralready have a Visitor struct, which i use. But in detailviewcontroller i don't know how to use Visitor struct again, i just "spit out" the values like ` override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        lblName.text = visitorName
        lblCompany.text = visitorCompany ....` So what i did i created an "temp" dictonary which holds the values from Visitor struct

Comment: Maybe if you showed more of your code I could help you better. You should still be able to use the struct within your file.

Comment: @rsmoz, i have edited my question a bit. Hope you give me some more tips. I am stuck with using the right "selected"/passing the right visitor struct to detail view controller
BTW i am developing for > iOS 8 and Contacts framework is > iOS 9 isn't it?

Comment: @rsmoz would you mind taking another look, how i can pass the right struct/class between viewcontrollers?

Comment: I'll take a look. Also, your Visitor is a class, not a struct. A struct would probably be better here.

Comment: A class is a reference type (uses pointers under the hood), a struct is a value type. There's a lot of good articles that explain this online.

Comment: You can just make a property on your destination view controller and set your its value to your struct.

Answer (score 6):

The dictionary type in Swift is called `Dictionary`. However, it is generic, meaning that you need to add `<>` after the type name to specify what type of dictionary you want it to be. In this case, it is `Dictionary<Int, String>`. This is because the variable that you are passing to the method (`visitorDict`) is of type `Dictionary<Int, String>`.

Write your function header like this:

```
func makeAndAddVisitorRecord2(visitorDict: Dictionary<Int, String>) -> ABRecordRef <AnyObject, AnyObject> {
```

If you want to go one step further, you can use the shorthand type name for dictionary:

```
func makeAndAddVisitorRecord2(visitorDict: [Int: String]) -> ABRecordRef <AnyObject, AnyObject> {
```

Also, if your keys for the dictionary are sequential, like 1, 2, 3, 4 ,5 etc, you can use an array instead:

```
func makeAndAddVisitorRecord2(visitorDict: Array<String>) -> ABRecordRef <AnyObject, AnyObject> {
```

And the shorthand for arrays is:

```
func makeAndAddVisitorRecord2(visitorDict: [String]) -> ABRecordRef <AnyObject, AnyObject> {
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify what type of dictionary it is in swift, like so:

```
func makeAndAddVisitorRecord2(visitorDict: [Int: String]) -> ABRecordRef <AnyObject, AnyObject> {
    let visitorRecord: ABRecordRef = ABPersonCreate().takeRetainedValue()
    ABRecordSetValue(visitorRecord, kABPersonFirstNameProperty, visitorDict[1], nil)
    ABRecordSetValue(visitorRecord, kABPersonLastNameProperty, visitorDict[2], nil)
    //ABRecordSetValue(visitorRecord, kABPersonEmailProperty, visitorDict[5], nil)

    let phoneNumbers: ABMutableMultiValue =
    ABMultiValueCreateMutable(ABPropertyType(kABMultiStringPropertyType)).takeRetainedValue()
    ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(phoneNumbers, visitorDict["visitorPhone"], kABPersonPhoneMainLabel, nil)
    ABRecordSetValue(visitorRecord, kABPersonPhoneProperty, phoneNumbers, nil)

    ABAddressBookAddRecord(addressBookRef, visitorRecord, nil)
    saveAddressBookChanges()

    return visitorRecord
}
```

Then you can use `makeAndAddVisitorRecord2(visitorDict)` and everything should work.

You collection types [apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html) has more in-depth examples.

Answer (score 0):

ABRecordRef is not generic, thus you cannot use like you did. Most likely you wanted to add the generic declaration to the Dictionary parameter.